# SQL Server Relation from 2 tables with partial keys

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key, relationship

Excuse me for poor english.

I'm designing a database and having 2 tables

**Labels**
Guid LabelID
varchar(5) Language
Varchar(50) LabelText

In this table the key are LabelID and Language

In second table I have some fields and  a field
Guid NameLabelId

When design diagram i try to create relationship from two tables using only NameLabelId and LabelId of the table Labels

I receive an error "The column do not match an existing primary Key or UNIQUE constraint"...

Can someone help me?

Thanks

MAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "primary" table in your relationship needs to either have its GUID column set as primary key, or with a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that the Labels table have the GUID not unique because for the same guid i can have N languages